# Duplicate macro definition after function declaration in CPython source code

Tags: c, oop, macros, cpython

I'm trying to go through the CPython source code to get a better understanding of Object Oriented C programming. I've come across the following snippet of code, and I'm not sure what to make of it.

```
// Test if the 'x' object is the 'y' object, the same as "x is y" in Python.
PyAPI_FUNC(int) Py_Is(PyObject *x, PyObject *y);
#define Py_Is(x, y) ((x) == (y))
```

There is a function that checks if two Python objects are identical, (and returns and `int` after PyAPI_FUNC is expanded), but immediately after that, a macro is defined with the same characteristic. For reference, here is the implementation of the `Py_Is` function:

```c
int Py_Is(PyObject *x, PyObject *y)
{
    return (x == y);
}
```

1. What is the difference (if there is any) between the two lines?
2. Why do both lines exist (are they being used for different builds)?
3. Ctrl+Click in VSCode brings me to different files,some using the function and others using the macro, how does each translation unit know which implementation to use?

Answer (score 0):

The function is defined, so from outside you can access it with the apt. It will appear in object and elf files. The macro is for your C code, so if you want to use `PyIs` it will just replace it with the `==` to make it faster and not call a function. The macro will not appear in a object or elf file, because it is only known during compile time.

Comment: Yeah, but why do both exist? Wouldn’t it be easier on compiler to just have the macro?

Comment: As I said, the macro is not included in object and elf files. This means, that `Py_Is()` can not be used outside of C files defining this macro.